# Flashtext keyword extraction is returning NaN at the end of the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, keyword

The KeywordProcessor used to extract keywords from FlashText is returning NaN at the end of the dataframe. The shape of the dataframe is (14.532.885, 6), where just one column (which contain sentences) is used to extract certain keywords.

The keywords extraction is correctly applied until the row 14.452.474. In other words, extraction is not applied to 80.411 final rows from the sentence column.

```py
from flashtext import KeywordProcessor

kp = KeywordProcessor()
kp.add_keywords_from_dict(keyword_dict=keywords_dict)

df['keywords'] = df['text'].apply(lambda sentence: kp.extract_keywords(sentence=sentence, span_info=False))


df[['text', 'keywords']][14452474:14452480]

output:
            text                                                keywords
14452474    it is monsoon season in stl today rain rain r...    [friendly]
14452475    hahahah pidgeons then                               []
14452476    nothing planned maybe ill go stay with u and h...   []
14452477    he wont disappoint                                  NaN
14452478    hi doc dickerson howdy opened a new twitter ac...   NaN
14452479    only one more class left for today then im hom...   NaN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A temporary solution is to create another column applying the same function since there are pure NaN values, after this combine both applied columns creating a third and new column and then make a drop to the two previous columns, because they will have NaN values.

```py
df['keywords_1'] = df['text'].apply(lambda sentence: kp.extract_keywords(sentence=sentence, span_info=False))

df['keywords_2'] = df['text'][14452477:].apply(lambda sentence: kp.extract_keywords(sentence=sentence, span_info=False))

df['keywords_result'] = df['text'][14452477:].apply(lambda x: kp.extract_keywords(x))
df['keyword'] = df['keywords_1'].combine_first(df['keywords_2'])
df.drop(columns=['keywords_1', 'keywords_2'])
```